# serve multiple directories in ngnix

Tags: php, nginx

I am trying to setup ngnix on my vps to serve different stuff e.g

`examplesite.com/` (main site)

`examplesite.com/pro/` (sub app)

`examplesite.com/ad/`

I wanted to be able to run different php apps from these directories.

My first task was to get `examplesite.com/pro` site working but I am having problems.

Please could someone help me ?

I just want to be able to run different things. I am trying install prosper202 on the `/pro/` directory.

My `default.conf` file :

```
server {

        listen 80;
        server_name .exmaple.com;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        client_max_body_size 512M;

        # Default location settings
        location / {
            index index.php;
        }

        location /pro {
            index index.php;
            try_files $uri $uri/ pro/index.php?$args;
        }

        # Redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

        location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

        # Pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server (locally with unix: param to avoid network overhead)
        location ~ \.php$ {
            # Prevent Zero-day exploit
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

            #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
            fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        }


---------------------------ngnix.conf------------------------------------- 

user nginx; 
worker_processes 4;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

}
```

My `error.log` file :

```
2014/11/06 11:51:41 [error] 3152#0: *1 directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html/" is forbidden, client: 14.16.105.135, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "IP" 2014/11/06 11:54:39 [error] 3218#0: *1 directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html/" is forbidden, client: 14.176.105.135, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "IP"
```

Comment: What does this have to do with php?

Comment: please ignore that i just want to be able to run different apps from sub directories.

Comment: Your `include fastcgi_params` is missing.

Answer (score 0):

There's a slash missing in your `try_files` directive.

Replace :

`pro/index.php?$args`

With :

`/pro/index.php$is_args$args`.

Comment: *1 directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html/" is forbidden, client: 86.185.90.203, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: ""  i am getting this error in the logs

Comment: @socils And ? Aren't you willing to make `/pro` work as asked ?

Comment: sorry I have added that but i am getting a blank page and that error

Comment: i have just noticed its got uri twice in that line   location. /pro {
        index  index.php;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /pro/index.php?$args;
        }

Comment: @socils That's not an issue it tells nginx to check for the URI and a potential directory. What's the result on the `/pro` part ?

Comment: nothing when i go to /pro/ a blank page appears. I have created a php info page and that is also blank.

Comment: @socils Does the /usr/share/nginx/html/pro/index.php file exist on your filesystem ? What's nginx error log ?

Comment: error log has the following :: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: ""
2014/11/06 16:13:35 [error] 4315#0: *1 directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html/" is forbidden, client: , server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: ""
2014/11/06 16:20:07 [error] 4315#0: *6 directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html/" is forbidden, client: ip server: ip, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "ip"

Comment: @socils Correct the Host header in the request, you are not sending anything matching this server block.